# How to transfer private repo to jupyter lab in vm?

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, virtual-machine

I want to clone my private repository from GitHub into virtual instance in Google Cloud, so that I can use it in Jupyter Lab.

I used this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos and the result is that I have a storage bucket with my repo compressed in tar.gz.

While using SSH in my virtual instance, I used command

`gsutil cp -r gs://MY_REPO_BUCKET /home/MY_USERNAME`

which apparently copied the repo to the instance. The thing is, I don't know where it is - couldn't find it in Jupyter Lab localhost.

Also, I tried to first clone my repo in Google Cloud Source Repositories and from there on copy it to my instance, but I don't know how to do it.

Any recommendations?